# How to make sure MacVim runs stable in terminal

Tags: vim, macvim

I have been using MacVim for a while. It has always been the non-terminal version. Recently I started using tmux and I would like to be able to use vim inside a tmux session. Only when I started to tweak my settings, I realised that the terminal experience will not be as smooth as the standalone MacVim one.

I am not talking about speed issues etc, it is mostly things like key mappings behaving differently etc. I already gave up trying to get the Option (Alt) key working, but at least I would like to have things stable in general.

For example a key mapping such as  that works perfectly in the non-terminal vim suddenly becomes , CTRL is no more a modifier? Discrepancies like that just make things extremely hard.

What are the most important configuration options that might improve MacVim's stability when running in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the answer is in focusing on various aspects individually and finding solutions for those. The first major issue is with the way keys are interpreted by the terminal application. In most cases, the terminal emulator will not be able to distinguish between CTRL-F10 and F10. So in cases where F10 is performing action_A, SHIFT-F10 is performing action_B and CTRL-F10 is performing action_C, there will be a confusion between action_B and action_C if CTRL key code is not interpreted correctly. I now know that iTerm2 is capable of broadcasting specific ESC sequences to the running process. I will focus on those.